# Fastest (portable) way to split an array in C#

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm writing a fully managed Mercurial library (to be used in a fully managed [Mercurial Server for Windows](http://hglabhq.com/), coming soon), and one of the most severe performance problems I'm coming across is, strangely enough, splitting an array in parts.

The idea is as follows: there's a byte array with size ranging from several hundred bytes to up to a megabyte and all I need to do with it is to split it in parts delimited by, in my specific case, `\n` characters.

Now what dotTrace shows me is that my ["optimized" version](http://pastie.org/4592828) of `Split` (the code *is* correct, [here's the naive](http://pastie.org/4592982) version I began with) takes up 11 seconds for 2,300 calls (there's an obvious performance hit introduced by the dotTrace itself, but everything's up to scale).

Here are the numbers:

- `unsafe` version: `11 297` ms for `2 312` calls
- managed ("naive") version: `20 001` ms for `2 312` calls

So here goes: what will be the fastest (preferably portable, meaning supporting both x86 and x64) way to split an array in C#.

Comment: Can we see your *"optimized" version of Split* so that we can think of how to improve it?

Comment: Portable in the sense of a portable class library as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx ?

Comment: You can find his code in the `"optimized" version` link.

Comment: I must be missing something, but why are you iterating in 8 byte increments? I think the fastest way is also the simplest. Iterate once through the array (byte by byte) and record the split indices. Allocate an array of byte arrays, using the difference between split indices as length for each individual byte array. Then copy the memory from the original array using some inbuild function. Evidently, the absolute fastest way is to not split at all, but create a structure that can be indexed like an array of byte arrays, but references the memory in the original allocation through offsets.

Comment: @L.B It's linked in the question itself.

Comment: @0xA3 "Portable" meaning that it would support both x86 and x64 (and, if that's at all possible, Mono).

Comment: @Gleno That was my very first attempt and it turned out to be much slower. I manually unrolled this loop and got a slight increase.

Comment: If you use memcmp, you restrict yourself to Microsofts C runtime... which probably isn't available on Mono.

Comment: @Sebastian That I know. I'm just trying to squeeze out maximum performance out of this seemingly simple routine.

Comment: @AntonGogolev What happens if just doing the byte-by-byte approach *without* even using unsafe code? How does that compare performance-wise? And byte-by-byte *with* unsafe code?

Comment: @pst That was the very first thing I tried: http://pastie.org/4592982

Comment: Can you check if and how many times your `CompareBuffers` and `GetBufferHash` are called?

Comment: First order of business, burn and bury `LinkedList`. It is *almost never* more efficient than a simple `List`. And for simple appending, it’s **never** faster.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek `CompareBuffers` and `GetBufferHash` are _not_ called in `Split`, so they can be ignored for the time being.

Comment: Are you sure adding into list is not slowing it down? Try pre-alocated array.

Comment: @pst Edited my question. Fully-managed version is almost two times slower.

Comment: Do you need to create new arrays? Wouldnt "view" into single array be enough?

Comment: @Euphoric That will require two passes over the source array. Way to expensive performance-wise. And I'm _not_ creating new arrays: `Segment` is just, as you say, a view into the source array.

Comment: With so many `if`s... aren't you possibly a victim of branch prediction?

Comment: @KonradRudolph `LinkedList.AddLast`: 92 ms for 570K calls. Negligible.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Not sure how branch prediction correlates with MSIL and JIT.

Comment: Try doing it with only bytes and maybe with value-termination.

Comment: There is literally nothing in your code that can take so much time except this loop of hihgly unpredictable branches. Please try with only a three or four split charactes in all data and see how long does it take then.

Comment: @harold That is what the existing code already does ..

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is, that you are doing a lot of complex operations in loop. This code removes all the operations except single addition and comparison inside a loop. Other complex stuff happens only when split is detected or at end of an array.

Also, it is hard to tell what kind of data you run your tests with, so this is only guesswork.

```
public static unsafe Segment[] Split2(byte[] _src, byte value)
{
    var _ln = _src.Length;

    if (_ln == 0) return new Segment[] { };

    fixed (byte* src = _src)
    {
        var segments = new LinkedList<Segment>(); // Segment[c];

        byte* last = src;
        byte* end = src + _ln - 1;
        byte lastValue = *end;
        *end = value; // value-termination

        var cur = src;
        while (true)
        {
            if (*cur == value)
            {
                int begin = (int) (last - src);
                int length = (int) (cur - last + 1);
                segments.AddLast(new Segment(_src, begin, length));

                last = cur + 1;

                if (cur == end)
                {
                    if (lastValue != value)
                    {
                        *end = lastValue;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            cur++;
        }

        return segments.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Fixed code, so it returns correct results.

Comment: That's a very tricky/clever use of the sentinel .. however, just the redux of one conditional/byte .. it would be nice to see timings.

Comment: Nice! `4 696` ms for `2 312` calls under dotTrace.

Comment: @pst: That's almost three times faster than my `unsafe` version.

Comment: You are overwriting the last byte of the array with the termination value. I am not sure if this is valid. A more data conserving approach would be to loop until the end and copy the last element as well if it is not a termination char.

Comment: @AloisKraus But then, there would be 2 comparisons each loop instead of 1. That is ~50% performance hit.

Comment: You could check if the array is terminated. If not use the two comparisons. Otherwise you can use the fast path which is the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

For Split, handling ulong on 32-bit machine is really slow, so definitely reduce to uint. If you really want ulong, implement two versions, one for 32-bit, one for 64-bit.

You should also measure whether handling byte at a time is faster.

Need to profile the cost of memory allocation. If it's bigger enough, try to reuse memory across multiple calls.

Other:

ToString: it's faster to use "(" + Offset.ToString() + ", " + Length.ToString() + ")";

GetHashCode: try fixed(byte * b = & buffer[offset])

---

This version should be really fast, if used multiple times. 
Key point: no new memory allocation after the internal array has expanded to the right size, minimal data copy.

```
class ArraySplitter
{
    private byte[] m_data;
    private int    m_count;
    private int[]  m_stops;

    private void AddRange(int start, int stop)
    {
        // Skip empty range
        if (start > stop)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Grow array if needed
        if ((m_stops == null) || (m_stops.Length < (m_count + 2)))
        {
            int[] old = m_stops;

            m_stops = new int[m_count * 3 / 2 + 4];

            if (old != null)
            {
                old.CopyTo(m_stops, 0);
            }
        }

        m_stops[m_count++] = start;
        m_stops[m_count++] = stop;
    }

    public int Split(byte[] data, byte sep)
    {
        m_data  = data;
        m_count = 0;      // reuse m_stops

        int last = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i ++)
        {
            if (data[i] == sep)
            {
                AddRange(last, i - 1);
                last = i + 1;
            }
        }

        AddRange(last, data.Length - 1);

        return m_count / 2;
    }

    public ArraySegment<byte> this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            index *= 2;
            int start = m_stops[index];

            return new ArraySegment<byte>(m_data, start, m_stops[index + 1] - start + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Test program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 1000 * 1000;

        byte[] data = new byte[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (byte) i;
        }

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)
        {
            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();

            int len = 0;

            foreach (var seg in data.MySplit(13))
            {
                len += seg.Count;
            }

            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("MySplit      : {0} {1,8:N3} ms", len, watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();

            ArraySplitter splitter = new ArraySplitter();

            int parts = splitter.Split(data, 13);

            len = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
            {
                len += splitter[i].Count;
            }

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("ArraySplitter: {0} {1,8:N3} ms", len, watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
MySplit      : 996093    9.514 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    4.754 ms
MySplit      : 996093    7.760 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    2.710 ms
MySplit      : 996093    8.391 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.510 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.677 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.468 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.685 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.370 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.700 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.425 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.669 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.519 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.844 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.416 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.721 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.685 ms
MySplit      : 996093    9.703 ms
ArraySplitter: 996093    3.470 ms
```

Comment: Do you really think your own resizable buffer is more efficient than the one provided by the framework (S.C.G.List)? – Konrad Rudolph yesterday 

It's basically the same thing with one level of indirection removed. Also, I think List<T> grows by 100% is too much, so I changed it to 50% growth. – Feng Yuan yesterday  

The built-in collections get some kind of special treatment by the CLR (manually re-implementing them 1:1 yields slower code!). I think the indirection is elided care of by the runtime. – Konrad Rudolph 17 hours ago

Comment: I checked array and List<T> access at assembly level last week. Trust me, array access is much faster than List<T> access.

Comment: Also, performance of List<T> can be greatly improved if you set an initial size to an adequate estimate, to avoid too many initial X2 resizes. I changed the naive approach I had posted above to not use yield return and have an initial size of a couple of thousand (actually I used an estimate of 1 new line per 100 bytes) and performance on both was about the same (still not as fast as the unsafe implementation).

Answer (score 2):

Anton,

I don't know if you are still interested in optimizing this since this thread is fairly old, however I saw that your code was pretty much the same in your online repository so I thought I would give it a shot. I looked over your HgSharp code on bitbucket.org while evaluating your HgLab application. I rewrote the function using native constructs which simplified it greatly. My tests resulted in better than half the time than your original routine. I tested it by loading a source file that was several megabytes and compared the timings to performance of the same operation using your original routine.

In addition to rewriting the basic logic, I decided to use the native `ArraySegment<>` built into the framework instead of your custom implementation. The only significant difference is that `ArraySegment<>` exposes a `Count` property instead of a `Length` property. The code below is does not require the unsafe keyword because I am not using pointers, however there does seem to be a slight performance improvement if it is changed to do so.

---

```
    public static ArraySegment<byte>[] SplitEx(this byte[] source, byte value) {
        var _previousIndex = -1;
        var _segments = new List<ArraySegment<byte>>();
        var _length = source.Length;

        if (_length > 0) {
            int _index;

            for (_index = 0; _index < _length; _index++) {
                var _value = source[_index];
                if (_value == value) {
                    _segments.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(source, _previousIndex + 1, _index - _previousIndex));
                    _previousIndex = _index;
                }
            }

            if (--_index != _previousIndex) {
                _segments.Add(new ArraySegment<byte>(source, _previousIndex + 1, _index - _previousIndex));
            }
        }

        return _segments.ToArray();
    }
```